# Ability to separate between levels in vocabulary hierarchy

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

In the frontend visualisation of vocabularies, is One in Drupal able to specify from which level in the vocabulary hierarchy one should display terms from?

If yes, how do you do this?

Thanks,

Espen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could use a module like [taxonomy_menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu) to show a list of taxonomy terms.

Alternatively, you could use a code solution like [`taxonomy_get_tree`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_tree/7) that allows selecting terms by parent tid and depth.